# Google search export: JSON wrong diacritics

Tags: json, search, encoding, export, invalid-characters

I have downloaded history of my Google search from [here](https://history.google.com/history/) but the diacritics (latin-extended characters) in JSON files (encoded in utf-8) are messed up.

E.g.:

```
dva na ôsmu
```

displays as

```
dva na �smu
```

and when I use JSON intedation package in Sublime Text, I get this:

```
dva na \ufffdsmu
```

All the special characters are replaced with this same broken character. Is there any way how to fix this, is simply Google exporting broken JSONs so non-english users can't use this export? I want to build app that will display statistics of words used in my searches but it is now possible with JSONs broken this way.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON seems to be corrupt. I inspected the text bytes with hex dump and the character is encoded as `0xEFBFBD`, which is [unicode replacement character](http://www.cogsci.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi?input=%EF%BF%BD&mode=char). The letter is already lost in the JSON and the character there is the replacement character.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: So it is on Google to fix its export app, right. Is there any way how to reportthis kind of bug?